# eVis plugin not showing in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to use the eVis plugin in QGIS 3.16.3 to display geotagged photos (as I have in the past without difficulty), but the plugin has totally disappeared. Not only can't I find it as an icon or under the Database menu, but it doesn't appear in the list of plugins (and yes, I am looking in the complete list of all plugins!).

Has it been moved somewhere I haven't come across or is it a bug?

Comment: eVis has been removed for [good reason](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/176) - I can still see it in QGIS 3.10.13.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For me personally, that's a great pity. I used it a lot previously and have now no idea of how to achieve the same result. Oh well... that's progress for you ;-) !!

Comment: EVIS is very useful for me and my co-workers. I am planning right now to revive it for my field work in Geology, remote sensing and disaster assessment. I might write it in python but im also planning to revive the C++ code. I should inform the original authors though...

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to import geotagged photos (exif data) into a vector layer you can use the Processing Toolbox instead, there is a process called "import geotagged photos". Here is a small video from my QGIS trainings: https://files.wheregroup.com/index.php/s/2qf7Yg4McKwgyRY

[image]

Comment: Thanks... yes, I had found that, but I had previously been using eVis to display photos and notes when clicking on a series of points and I don't think that's possible with that function. I have been experimenting with map tips, but as far as I can tell for the moment, you have to enter the path to each photo separately which would be pretty laborious as I have about a hundred photos. I'll keep experimenting!

Comment: When the photos are imported with the tool above, the table contains all the information (path to image and so on). If you use the identify tool afterwards, the photo will be displayed in the info widget.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I obviously need to experiment further as until now I haven't been able to get the photo to display... I'll work on it!